# $\nabla \sqrt{\rho} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \implies \rho \in L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, mathematical-physics

I found this in the

```
INTERNATIONAL JOURNAL OF QUANTUM CHEMISTRY, VOL XXIV, 250 (1983)
```

inside the paper of *Elliot H. Lieb* with the title *Density Functionals for Coulomb Systems* and I really don't get it. If somebody could tell me why this holds or give me a hint i would be very thankful.

**EDIT:**

$\rho : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and  $\sqrt{\rho} \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3) = W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: There need to be more assumptions (otherwise any constant $\rho$ is a counterexample)

Comment: Sorry! I put them at the and of the original post. So as $\rho \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ it can't be a constant except 0, right?

Answer (score 2):

By Sobolev embeeding, from $\sqrt\rho\in H^1(\mathbb R^3)$ it follows that
$$
\sqrt \rho \in L^6(\mathbb R^3),
$$
which implies
$$
\rho \in L^3(\mathbb R^3).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) You work fast here on StackExchange! :O

Answer (score 1):

A short answer, if $\sqrt{\rho} \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, then by the Sobolev embedding ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem with $1/p^* = 1/6 = 1/2 -1/3 = 1/p - 1/n$), we have $\sqrt{\rho} \in L^6(\mathbb{R}^3)$, which then results in $\rho \in L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$. You can even get estimates on the norm this way.

edit: 36 seconds too late...

Comment: Thank you very much! You both were really fast! :)